# WCF, error 405 on Windows 2016 but not on 2008

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf

WCF service running under ASP.NET 4.52, Silverlight client. The app used to work when hosted on Windows 2008 R2. Now I've set it up on a Windows 2016 server, and the very first service call errors out with error 405 - method not allowed. The method here is POST. The error description goes:

> 405 - HTTP verb used to access this page is not allowed.

On the Windows 2008 based instance, it's POST also, but the back end has no problem with that. The service uses HTTPS with Windows auth.

The relevant Web.config bits are:

```
    <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="winAuthBasicHttpBinding" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647">
          <readerQuotas maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxDepth="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"/>
          <security mode="Transport">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Ntlm"/>
          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="Foo.Web.Services.FooBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
          <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="Foo.Web.Services.FooBehavior" name="Foo.Web.Services.FooService">
        <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="winAuthBasicHttpBinding" contract="Foo.Web.Services.IFooService">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost"/>
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
      </service>
    </services>
    </system.serviceModel>
```

The erroring method has no annotations other than `[OperationContract]`. The interface only has `[ServiceContract]`. The service class has:

```cs
    [WcfErrorBehavior]
    [WcfSilverlightFaultBehavior]    
    [AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
```

It might be relevant that the method has no arguments; I believe more recent versions of WCF use GET for those. The app is quite old.

The error reproduces with a generic HTTP client, it's not specific to the Silverlight front-end.

Looks like a difference in machine-level WCF configuration between .NET versions. Less likely, it could be that a Windows component is missing on the Windows 2016 box.

EDIT: enabled request tracing, got something back. There's a notification `EXECUTE_REQUEST_HANDLER` sent to `StaticFileModule`. A WCF service is most definitely not a static file.

Comment: Did you try enabling older versions of the .NET Framework on the 2016 server?

Comment: How, please? I thought the whole 4.x branch is enabled by default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anyway, I want to reply to this thread. it might be useful to whoever encountered a similar issue.
@Seva Alekseyev, as you mentioned, for hosting WCF service created by Webhttpbinding in IIS, and some other protocol, such as Nettcpbinding, we should enable some kinds of Windows features.
[image]
For NetTcpbinding, we also need to enable the below Windows feature.
[image]
Feel free to let me know if there is anything I can help with.

Answer (score 0):

Under Server Manager, roles and features, "HTTP Activation" was missing in the WCF category. My second hunch was right. That said, the error is somewhat misleading, so I'll leave this question here for posterity's sake.